# Do java.util.Collections and java.util.Collection have any relationship in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, interface

I am reading through collections to see hierarchy of implementations from Javadocs.

`Collections` is declared as `public class Collections extendds Object`

`Collection<E>` is declared as `public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>`

`AbstractCollection` is declared as `public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E>`

`AbstractList` is declared as `public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E>`

my questions are
1) Is there any connections between `Collections and Collection`. I do not see anything `extending Collections Class`?

2) what is the need for `AbstractList` class, since the methods implemented in `AbstractList` class such as `listIterator` could as well be abstracted in `List Interface` and the implementing class could as well implement such methods?

Comment: [Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself): one of the purposes of `abstract` classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There's no relationship in the class hierarchy.  `Collections` is just a class full of utility methods that can be used on a `Collection` classes.
2. `AbstractList` is just a nice helper for people who want to implement their own `List` class.  Extending `AbstractList` saves you from writing a lot of boilerplate code because you can just reuse the code that's already in there. As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) says:

   > This class provides a skeletal implementation of the List
   >   interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface
   >   backed by a "random access" data store (such as an array).

Answer (score 1):

There is an informal convention of naming a utility class (a class full of all or mainly static methods) by adding an s to the name of a related "real" class.  For example, the [Google Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has utility classes Booleans, Bytes, ByteStreams, Callables, Floats, ...